# Client Sorter - Possible?

Tags: client

So what I wonder is if it's possible to make a client sorter that would make clients overlapping eachother. For instance if I have 5 browsers opened and I want to make them overlap each other, is it possible to make a program like this?

I want to use it for a game where I usually may have up to 10 clients opened and therefore it would be nice to have a program sorting them up quickly.

If this is possible. Can the program be written in Java or what language should it be written in?

Answer (score 1):

Although your question is quite fuzzy (e.g. what is a client???) I assumy you mean that you want to tile your windows in some way. Additionally I assume that you would be happy to use an existing program if there is one. There are. Take a look at

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiling_window_manager

which is precisely what I think you are looking for. There are links to existing programs to that page as well (some are free).

Comment: Ye, sorry for that. My vocabular is not that good and therefore I did not find precise words for what I am looking for! I will take a look into that one! Thanks for taking your time!

Comment: If this is what you meant, please approve my answer (that's how the Stackoverflow community works, as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq/#howtoask))